# Filtering URL To Get Page Number With Regex On PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I had to filter this URL below to get page number :

```
http://www.domain.com/string/999/string-article-title/999
```

I want to filter the last 3 digit number ( this is related to page ) within this url patterns

I've try this, but had no success :

```
preg_match("/http::\/\/www.domain.com\/string\/999\/string-article-title\/^[0-9]{3}$", $nlink, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
```

How can I filter those pattern, so I can get the URL from

```
"http://www.domain.com/string/999/string-article-title/1 to 999"
```

PS: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could get `999` like:

```
$ret = array_pop(explode('/', $nlink));
```

Comment: no, thats a dirty works. Because, beside that patterns, I have more url to explode with different step

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
preg_match("/(?<=^http:\/\/www\\.domain\\.com\/string\/999\/string-article-title\/)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$/", $nlink, $matches);
```

Results to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 999
)
```

The regexp can be easily extended to cover any number of digits at the end of request:

```
/(?<=^http:\/\/www\\.domain\\.com\/string\/999\/string-article-title\/)[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

Comment: this is true for 3 full digit only.

Comment: @user2329193 Sorry, it was working for case of 2 or 3 digits only. Now it covers cases 1-3 digits. I've also added a version that covers case of more than 3 digits at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
 $nlink='http://www.domain.com/string/999/string-article-title/999';
 preg_match("/http:\/\/www.domain.com\/string\/999\/string-article-title\/([0-9]{3})/", $nlink, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
 echo '<pre>';      
 print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.domain.com/string/999/string-article-title/999
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 999
            [1] => 54
        )

)
```

Comment: I've try this. Its only true for 3 full digit only.

Comment: You asked about 3 and there is {3} in your example. If you need to find any amount of numbers use: ([0-9]+)  instead of ([0-9]{3})

Answer (score 0):

```
$page_number = substr( $url, strrpos($url, "/") + 1 ); // returns 999
if ( $page_number >= 1 && $page_number <= 999 ) 
{
    // match
}
```

Comment: ah yess, with a little bit work, I can get the maximum page from specified url.

Answer (score 0):

Without `preg_*`, sweet and simple:

```
$a = array_reverse(explode("/",rtrim($url,"/")));
echo $a[0];

or

$a = array_pop(explode("/",rtrim($url,"/")));
echo $a;
```

The complete URL is assumed in `$a`. This code will work even if `$url = "http://www.test.com/999/";`with a slash in the end because of `rtrim`.